# node:internal/errors:464 ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err); Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

All functions are working well, but this error comes two more put or delete functions are called again and again it happens that time

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\ND\StudioProjects\pos\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\ND\StudioProjects\pos\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\ND\StudioProjects\pos\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
    at deleteAddItem (file:///C:/Users/ND/StudioProjects/pos/controller/bill/addItem.controller.js:41:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

```
const deleteAddItem = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const getItem = req.body;
    const deleteItem = await AddItem.findOneAndDelete(getItem);
    if (!deleteItem) res.status(203).json({ msg: "No bill available" });
    return res.status(202).json({ msg: "Bill Deleted" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ msg: "Internal Server Error deleteAddItem", error });
  }
};
```

Router file

```
billRouter.delete("/deleteAddItem", deleteAddItem);
```

I have no idea what's happening this is!

Comment: the error occurs when you try to send the response that has already been sent to the client, to avoid the issue not send multiple responses or you can return your response like `return res.status(201).json({ msg: "Bill create" });`